# Fuzzy string matching: which tool?

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

I have a large number of strings containing a product name and a few other properties (size, volume, age, etc). But the strings are not standardized at all. Product names might be misspelled, volume might be in a different notation (0.5l, 1/2 liter, 500ml, etc). The number of variations is limited though, there are for instance only a few hundred products. What tools can I use to analyze each string and tell me if it contains certain tokens? My guess is that some sort of learning mechanism would be useful, but I'm not sure which tools would offer just that. I've looked at ElasticSearch, but I'm not sure if that's the way to go. All my data is currently in a PostgreSQL db and I've looked at pg_grm as well. Again, not sure if that fits my need.

One solution I've been thinking about is maintaining a list of proper keywords and, per string, see if the string contains any of the keywords. I'm not sure if this would work and, if it would, how to efficiently and effectively implement it in postgresql

**EDIT**
Here are a few example lines I'm trying to extract keywords from:

```
wine Bardolo red 1L 12b 12% 
La Tulipe, 13* box 3 bottles, 2005
Great Johnny Walker 7CL 22% red label
Wisky Jonny Walken .7 Red limited editon
```

I've done quite some searching by now but have yet to find a proper way to solve this problem.

Comment: Perhaps analyzing the entire string as an ngram using the `ngram` tokenizer would work for you with Elasticsearch? It will allow sub-word fuzzy matching.

Comment: Maybe, but I think I need sub-string fuzzy matching instead of sub-word fuzzy matching. Would that work as well?

Answer (score 0):

I've used pg_trgm extension for similar task (I was comparing misspelled address lines and company names) along with clustering algorithm (may be not needed in your case).

It's done it's job with some data preparations (regexp replacements).
May be not very easy but I'm sure it's possible to solve your problem too. And index support in pg_trgm is great.

Comment: Thanks, but addresses have a somewhat similar order of 'words'. In my case the 'tokens' I'm looking for could be anywhere in the string (and misspelled as well).